# Рандомная смена кодировки в php+ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, кодировка

Всем привет.

Случилась следующая странная ситуация:
Ajax-ом отправляется запрос, в целевом php-файле в цикле прогонялся вывод текста с кириллицей, в определённый момент возникает как будто смена кодировки с utf-8 на win1251 (или что-то похожее). Код вывода:

```
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
    var_dump("ыИжевы");
}
```

вывод выглядит так:
string(12) "ыИжевы"
string(12) "ыИжевы"
string(12) "ыИжевы"
string(12) "ыИжевы"
string(12) "ыИжевы"
string(12) "ыИжевы"
string(12) "ыИже²Ñ"
string(12) "ÑÐÐ¶ÐµÐ²Ñ"
string(12) "ÑÐÐ¶ÐµÐ²Ñ"
string(12) "ÑÐÐ¶ÐµÐ²Ñ"
string(12) "ÑÐÐ¶ÐµÐ²Ñ"
string(12) "ÑÐÐ¶ÐµÐ²Ñ"
string(12) "ÑÐÐ¶ÐµÐ²Ñ"
string(12) "ÑÐжевы"
string(12) "ыИжевы"
string(12) "ыИжевы"
string(12) "ыИжевы"
string(12) "ыИжевы"

Причём на разных машинах появление бага стабильно, но поведение различно (например но одной возникает если писать ыИжев или как-то сокращать/изменять слово)

Ajax отправляется обычный POST запрос. Проект пустой (всего 2 файла .php). Данная проблема была протестирована на трёх разных машинах (разные сервера) на разных версиях php (5.6, 7.2), Apache/2.4.29(Ubuntu), в заголовках везде был указан utf-8.
Из-за чего такое может быть?

UPD (весь код):
index.php

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "send_mail.php",
                success: function () {
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        });
```

send_mail.php:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$str = 'ыИжевы';
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
    var_dump($str);
};
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать вывод в лог-файл и посмотрите как там отображается текст до отправки браузеру.

Comment: Нужен полный код. PHP и JS

Comment: @MAX, в файлах текст отображается нормально.

Comment: Значит PHP отправляет нормально. Дальше пробуйте смотреть через консоль браузера что приходит в ответ аяксу. То есть проверяйте  каждый шаг — так вы определите на каком этапе происходит проблема.

Comment: @MAX, извиняюсь, неверно написал в предыдущем комментарии. В вопросе  представлен вывод через "Сеть"->"XHR" в браузере. Если выводить через консоль ответ аякса, то ответ приходит без проблем кодировки. Изначально проблема обнаружилась, при отправке данных курлом на другой сервер, где он не смог распарсить строку.

Comment: То есть проблема в другом сервере?.. Всё-таки вы уточните хотя бы где именно возникает проблема. А то из ваших ответов получается, что PHP и Ajax работают нормально.

Comment: @MAX, проблема возникает не на другом сервере, на другом сервере уже следствие...
Я понимаю, что выглядит так, будто проблемы нет, раз в файл записывается нормально и аякс получает не битый ответ. Однако по факту, если тот же текст отправлять курлом на другой сервер или вардампить его и смотреть результат не через консоль, то виден тот результат, что описан в вопросе. То есть рандомное изменение кодировки выводимого текста...

Comment: Вывод вы где смотите?

Comment: @MAX в браузере, через "Сеть"

Comment: То есть в Консоли браузера всё ок, а во вкладке Сеть проблема?

Comment: @MAX, именно так.

Comment: Чудеса. :-) В другом браузере проверяли?

Comment: @MAX Да, в хроме примерно то же самое. Потому сюда и обратился скорее за предположением. Потому как уже совсем заканчиваются идеи в чем кроется проблема. Причем коряжится фактически на середине вывода, потом в обратное состояние возвращается. На разных машинах смотрели. Пример вывода несложный. Был бы рад, если кто-нибудь ещё потестировал, тоже будет информация хоть какая. Только на разных машинах почему-то на разные длины фраз коряжится. Например "Ижев" без проблем проходит, а "Ижевы" уже с портится. Думаю, уже понятно, как я отчаялся)

Comment: Единственное что приходит на ум — это какая-то проблема с непосредственным выводом через var_dump. 100 раз в цикле, может что-то и сбивается. Попробуйте простым echo, либо включите буферизацию (ob_start) в начале цикла, а после вывод буфера.

Comment: @MAX Проблема изначально была обнаружена в отправке этих данных курлом (значит они и без вывода, в самой переменной битые). Но и версию с ob_cache мы проверили и с echo тоже - везде повторяется такая ситуация.

Comment: Тогда сложно что-то сказать. Может вирус/плагин/файрвол/и т.п. «бьёт» http-ответ. :-)